# flexbox how to find out how much is "remaining space" in absolute units

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this problem that i am not sure how to face.

There is a flexbox, column oriented, which has three children: top, middle and bottom. In the middle child i need to nest a 3rd party component that demands to know, in absolute units (e.g. px), the size of its container to render properly.

The only solution i can think of is to somehow find out the size in pixels of the middle container after the CSS engine calculates it and then use js to set the size.

To make things worse, the component does not work well if one sets its height  in percentages

So,

```
<div id="componentPlaceHolder" style="height: 10%;"></div>
```

does not work. You have to do something in the likes of

```
<div id="componentPlaceHolder" style="height: 455px;"></div>
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Did you try other units like rem? That might work since it's based on the 'm' pixel width and seems more predictable than a percentage that might calculate to be 20.222222%

Comment: If you set the `html, body: height to %` then your `div: 10%` will work. You can use `flex-shrink` or `flex-grow` to control the `div` width or set a `%` using `flex-basis` .

Comment: What would happen if you set the middle component to `flex: 1 0 1px` ( which is the same as `height: 1px; flex-grow: 1`)? This provides a pixel height reference, but also makes the item expand across all available space.

Comment: @Michael_B the problem is the 3rd party component. It takes  1px as the height to initialize, the containing div accurately resizes to fill the remaining space but the component stays 1 px tall.

Comment: @Adam sadly that does not work. I can explicitly set all sizes in the hierarchy up to the html tag, but unless I use absolute units, the goddam component renders with its default dimensions.

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo can you please add more code or/and link to **jsfiddle**. are you trying to get the width or the height of the targeted `div`? [Check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLqrb3hL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to determine the height of the middle div:

```
var middleDivHeight = getElementById("middleDivId").css( "height" );
```

This will return a number in px, then you can set the height of the component with JS:

```
document.getElementById("componentId").style.height = middleDivHeight;
```